# "OR" filter for `fnFilter` , DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to call `fnFilter` method to filter the first column with a filter functionality of "OR" operations.
Like

```
 thisObj.dataTable.fnFilter(keywordsArray,0);//TODO, OR FILTER
```

I will have a array like ["P1","P2"] which stands for the products code I need to filter out.

And say my the table contains row of product code P1,P2,P3, when I pass an array of ["P1", "P2"], I need to view the first two rows.

Comment: you can also use my [yadcf](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) plugin (among many filter types you can use the multi_selct) notice first column filter: http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html

Comment: dataTables 1.9.x, 1.10.x or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use regex to solve this problem:

```
       var regArray=[];
        var regexStr=".*"//by default, select all
        if(filter_not_empty){//your condition here,use regex to filter 
            for(var i=0;i<select_val.length;i++){
                regArray.push(select_val[i])//push the select text.
            }
            regexStr=checkval.join('|');//join a Regex Expresion
        }
        thisObj.dataTable.fnFilter(regexStr,0,true);//filter the first(0) coloumn using regex
```

Comment: This is obviously the simplest way, but it's also the less-compatible one (at least on version 1.9 of dataTables)... This will work great when the strings in the array are simple (one word, no special characters, no spaces), but let's say you have the following string in the array - "spec.ial/str'ing.here? (yes)". From my recent experience with regex on fnFilter (again, version 1.9), this will not work properly (or not at all, for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` instead. The below function works with both 1.9.x and 1.10.x versions :

```
//a general filtering function taking an array of values
function filter(values, colIndex, match) {
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
            for (i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
                if (match) {
                    if (data[colIndex] == values[i]) return true;
                } else {
                    if (data[colIndex].indexOf(values[i])>=0) return true;
                }     
            }
            return false;
        }     
    );
    table.fnDraw();
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop();
}
```

activated by a button, filtering on column #3 with exact match :

```
$("#filter").click(function() {
    filter( ['1.7', '1.8'], 3, true );
});
```

As for the question, call `filter(keywordsArray, 0);`

1.9.x demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/uu7gcwvf/**
1.10.x demo (same code, different library) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hrm97wd0/**

If you want to make a pure 1.10.x `DataTable()` filter :

```
function filter(values, colIndex, match) {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
            for (i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
                if (match) {
                    if (data[colIndex] == values[i]) return true;
                } else {
                    if (data[colIndex].indexOf(values[i])>=0) return true;
                }     
            }
            return false;
        }     
    );
    table.draw();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qgjjafeu/**